# changing mouse acceleration and speed xinput

Tags: mouse, xinput

How do I disable mouse acceleration and still get my mouse to go fast? The settings in the menu are too slow and don't disable the acceleration fully. I've tried doing `xinput set-prop '11' 'Device Accel Profile' -1` and `xinput set-prop '11' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1/5`.

Although it gets rid of the acceleration the mouse moves very slow now. Even `xset m 2 0` doesn't change anything after I enter the xinput codes.

How can I increase mouse speed while getting rid of mouse acceleration?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 6):

The way to set it is in terminal not `xset m`.

First, use `xinput --list --short` and write down your mouse ID. Mine is (8). Save it.

Next, in the terminal, type:

```
xinput --list-props yourMouseId
```

Press enter and find the `Device Accel Constant Deceleration #`. Mine is (270). Write it down, behind your mouses ID.

Now, in the terminal, type:

```
xinput --set-prop 8 270 7
```

If this is too slow, retype the command but lower the last #. Try 6 or 5 or 4 and down till you got the speed you like.

One last thing: If your mouse is too slow, try going into the settings of mouse and touchpad and use the speed slider there to your liking.

Comment: `libinput Accel Speed (287): -0.500000` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Device Accel Constant Deceleration` can't be set lower than 1.0, so it sets it to 1.0 when you try setting it to 1/5. You can check this using `xinput list-props 11`. (I'm actually guessing it doesn't read the "/5"-part, because I get an error message when trying to set it to for example 0.5, but setting it to 1/5 actually sets it to 1.0).

If you don't want acceleration (which I completely agree with), the only thing you can do to improve the pointer speed is to set `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` to 1.0. If the pointer doesn't move fast enough for you then, I think the only fix is to get a mouse with higher DPI (or set your mouse to a higher DPI if you have a mouse with adjustable DPI).

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 14.04 system, I seem to be able to accomplish scaling of the mouse
sensitivity by adjusting 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration'.
It doesn't accept a numerator/denominator (if you try to give it one,
it just takes the numerator), but it does accept numbers less than 1 (the lower the number, the faster your pointer will go w.r.t. how fast you move the mouse).
So, try using .2 instead of 1/5.  xinput --list-props 11  should then show it as .200000.