# Lock the mouse cursor to one screen in Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, 19.10

Lock the mouse cursor to one screen in Linux

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with 2 screens with different resolution. (one 1440p other 1080p) Getting the mouse cursor moving accidentally from one screen to another is really annoying, especially annoying when gaming.

Is it possible to temporarily lock the mouse to one screen, and possibly releasing it with a shortcut? or locking it until i alt tab out of my program/game.

Comment: If you've not already found this, you can try an old answer: https://superuser.com/a/177487/425226. It's an old answer so everything might not work but you can give it a go

Comment: you can also try this package from the same question https://github.com/CyberShadow/hax11

Comment: I tried it with the old way But it didn't work :(. It's way to outdated . Also my second screen is currently to the left. @akxer

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like at [this link](https://medium.com/@coladibriatico94/lock-graphic-tablet-to-one-screen-on-linux-d14ce649da5d):

- find the name of monitor with `xrandr` for example "LVDS1".
- find the name of your input device with `xinput` for example "HUION H420 Mouse"
- and at the end lock the input to the screan with `xinput map-to-output "HUION H420 Mouse" "LVDS1"`

Comment: This plus a keyboard shortcut makes it perfect :-) I used that in the past to re-map the touch screen to just the "touch" screen when using two monitors, nevermind it will help me again.

Comment: Unfortunately this also causes my mouse speed to go real slow. You can fix it with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332798/changing-mouse-acceleration-and-speed-xinput), but it's not very nice.